# How can I use 3 different versions of keras in a single code?

Tags: keras, version

I want to use keras **2.4.3** for some part of code and similarly I have to use versions **2.3.0** and **2.1.6** for other two parts of the same code.
please help

```
pip install keras==2.4.3
pip install keras==2.3.0
pip install keras==2.1.6
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't think it is possible, it would make little sense and this is not even considering all the possible incompatibilities between keras versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and happy new year, I need to run two different CNN models which requires two different versions